# How can I get distinct counts with different where clauses on the same field?

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

How can I get `DISTINCT` row `COUNT`s with different conditions in a single `SELECT` statement, and if count is zero get zero as a result?

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.DeviceFilter,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM DeviceLicense AS B WHERE A.DeviceFilter = B.DeviceFilter AND b.OrganizationId = 1001) 
FROM
    DeviceLicense AS A
GROUP BY
    A.DeviceFilter
```

[image]

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT A.DeviceFilter, (SELECT count(*) FROM DeviceLicense AS B WHERE A.DeviceFilter=B.DeviceFilter AND b.OrganizationId = 1001 FROM DeviceLicense AS A GROUP BY A.DeviceFilter

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you really want a [`PIVOT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140308.aspx).

First, we'll create your `DeviceLicense` table, and populate some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DeviceLicense
(
    SINo int NOT NULL
    , DeviceFilter nvarchar(50) NULL
    , OrganizationID int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.DeviceLicense (SINo, DeviceFilter, OrganizationID)
VALUES (1, NULL, 1001)
    , (2, NULL, 1001)
    , (3, 'iPad', 1000)
    , (4, 'iPad', 1001)
    , (5, 'MACommon', 1000)
    , (6, 'MACommon', 1001);
```

This is the `PIVOT` statement.  As you can see below, the statement adds a `PIVOT` clause to a typical `SELECT` statement to allow rows to be transformed via an aggregate into columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.DeviceLicense
    ) src
PIVOT (
    COUNT(SINo)
    FOR OrganizationID IN (
        [1000]
        , [1001]
    )
) pvt;
```

The results of the `select` statement above:

```
+--------------+------+------+
| DeviceFilter | 1000 | 1001 |
+--------------+------+------+
| NULL         |    0 |    2 |
| iPad         |    1 |    1 |
| MACommon     |    1 |    1 |
+--------------+------+------+
```

I haven't added all your sample data, so the output is limited, but you can see there are columns for each `OrganizationID`, and rows for each `DeviceFilter`.  In future, know that it helps us give you a better answer if you provide the scripted DDL for the objects involved (the tables, etc), along with a table of data, not a screenshot.

Here, I'll attempt to show the `PIVOT` clause syntax in an understandable way:

```
PIVOT (
    COUNT(SINo)
    FOR OrganizationID IN (
        [1000]
        , [1001]
    )
) pvt;
```

The first obvious bit is the presence of the `PIVOT` keyword.  This tells SQL Server we're going to provide the following items:

1. a column from the main "src" `SELECT` query, wrapped in an aggregate, such as `MAX()`, `SUM()`, or in our case, `COUNT()`.
2. The column headings we want, in the form of a list of the values present in a column from the "src" `SELECT` query.  In this case, the `OrganizationID` column contains the values 1000 and 1001, which we'd like displayed as headings.  The `OrganizationID` column might contain other values, such as 1002, but the way the `PIVOT` clause is written now, values from those rows will not be displayed.  In order to have 1002 values shown as another column, we'd need to define the pivot like this:

   ```
   PIVOT (
       COUNT(SINo)
       FOR OrganizationID IN (
           [1000]
           , [1001]
           , [1002]  --note this creates an additional column in the output!
       )
   ) pvt;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE` statements within a count, just like you can with `SUM` aggregates:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN A = '1' THEN B END),  -- Only count B where A is 1
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B = C THEN B END),  -- Only count B where it's the same as C
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  -- Count rows where B equals C
FROM
    DeviceLicense
```